# CATALINA_BASE is not working in log4j.properties with Struts 1.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, tomcat6, struts-1

I need to deploy  war file with different proerties file and log4j file to 2 different instance of tomcat 6 at linux server. I am using Struts 1.2 . So there is not much work required , i only add log4j.properties to src folder and add the jar file.

Things are working very fine at my local (Eclipse+Window +Tomcat 6)

My log4j.properties file

log4j.rootCategory=INFO,dest2,debug

```
# Write to log file and roll over after certain size
log4j.appender.dest2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest2.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.dest2.File=${catalina.base}/logs/boReports.log
log4j.appender.dest2.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.dest2.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest2.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

it is working fine at dev envrionment and it creates boReports.log inside my tomcat logs folder.

```
I used log4j.appender.dest2.File=${catalina.home}/logs/boReports.log
```

As there is only one insantance of tomcat at my local

But when i deployed the war inside one instance of tomcat at linux , it is not working anymore.

I tried

`log4j.appender.dest2.File=${catalina.home}/logs/boReports.log`  also (though there is multiple instance of tomcat , i should not try this ) but did not find any luck on this.

It would be great help if someone point me what should be exact configuration to run the same at linux machine.

I did enough googling and only found 
log4j.appender.dest2.File=${catalina.base}/logs/boReports.log

So plzz help 
Thanks in Advance
Kindly suggest , if any more information is required

Comment: What system properties do you see if you have a simple JSP with: "`<pre><% for( java.util.Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : System.getProperties().entrySet()) { out.println(entry); } %></pre>`" Do you see the tomcat properties?